# Amazon RDS replication with external slave

Tags: replication, aws, amazon-rds

I've recently configured a replication with an external MySQL master and RDS as slave but now I need to reverse that config and use RDS as master and the other instance as slave.
Actually I use a vpn and the other instance is outside AWS.

I changed the server host and password but I got this error:

> 141103 11:35:44 [ERROR] Error reading packet from server: Binary log
>   is not open ( server_errno=1236) 141103 11:35:44 [ERROR] Slave I/O:
>   Got fatal error 1236 from master when reading data from binary log:
>   'Binary log is not open', Error_code: 1236 141103 11:35:44 [Note]
>   Slave I/O thread exiting, read up to log 'mysql-bin.000007', position
>   284079763 141103 11:37:09 [Note] Error reading relay log event: slave
>   SQL thread was killed

Perhaps I didn't get the right log filename and postion? but I can't find them in to RDS

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

For RDS to have binlogs, there are a couple non-obvious tricks.  First, you need to set the "backup retention period" to at least 1 day.  This turns on binlogging.

Then, in order to prevent a ridiculous rollover rate in the logs:

```
call mysql.rds_set_configuration('binlog retention hours', 24);
```

Here's some documentation that Amazon provides for dumping the database and starting up the replication:  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Exporting.NonRDSRepl.html

Answer (score 1):

I just set up replication from an Aurora instance to a 5.7 MySQL RDS instance following this guide provided by AWS,

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Aurora.Overview.Replication.MySQLReplication.html

Though there is Aurora in the title, it has relevant information for setting up an external slave from both Aurora and regular MySQL RDS.